# Sets homotopically equivalent

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, homotopy-theory

Let $\Omega$ a smooth bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\Omega_{r}^{-}=\{x\in \Omega, \rm dist(x, \partial \Omega)>r\}$

I must prove that for $r>0$ small enought, we have thar $\Omega$ and $\Omega_{r}^{-}$ are homotopically equivalent : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HomotopyEquivalence.html

So i let $\rm f: \Omega\rightarrow \Omega_{r}^{-}$ defined by $f(x)$ such that $\rm dist(f(x),\partial\Omega)>r$ and $\rm g:\Omega_{r}^{-}\rightarrow \Omega$ defined by $g(x)$ where $\rm dist(x,\partial \Omega)>r$

after that i must prove that $f\circ g$ is homotopic to $id_{\Omega_{r}^{-}}$ and $g\circ f$ is homotopic to $id_{\Omega}$

So i define $H: \Omega_{r}^{-}\times[0,1]\rightarrow \Omega_{r}^{-}$ such that $H(x,0)=f\circ g(x), H(x,1)=id_{\Omega_{r}^{-}}(x)$

I define $H$ by $H(x,t)= t id_{\Omega_{r}^{-}}(x)+(1-t) f\circ g(x)$

But How to prove that $$\rm dist(t ~id_{\Omega_{r}^{-}}(x)+(1-t) f\circ g(x),\partial\Omega)>r$$ ?

I need your help please

Thank you

Comment: This is an application of the tubular neighborhood theorem. Do you know that theorem?

Comment: And by the way, the formula $f(x) = \text{dist}(x,\partial\Omega)$ defines an $\mathbb{R}$-valued function, not an $\Omega^-_r$-valued function.

Comment: no @LeeMosher i don't know it

Comment: you are right, but then how to define $f(x)\in \Omega_{r}^{-}$ please

Comment: Can you please @LeeMosher do a correction for my work please

Comment: @LeeMosher i edited my question, can you see if it is right now ? thank you

Comment: are you there @LeeMosher ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tubular_neighborhood Using the statement of that theorem it should be simple to prove what you want. The proof of that theorem can be found in the textbooks at the end of the Wikipedia page provided; I suggest Hirsch's book.

Comment: But i don't understand this theorem and what is the relation with my problem @LeeMosher